# Android check latest dependencies versions

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

I am using multi module project and I have my dependencies centralised in `buildSrc` folder. I have a `Dependencies.kt` that looks like -

```
object Versions {
    const val CORE_KTX = "1.3.2"
    const val FRAGMENT_KTX = "1.2.5"
    ...
}

object LibraryDependencies {
   const val ANDROIDX_CORE_KTX = "androidx.core:core-ktx:${Versions.CORE_KTX}"
   const val FRAGMENT_KTX = "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:${Versions.FRAGMENT_KTX}"
   ...
}
```

In my modules, in their respective `build.grdle`, I use it as -

```
dependencies {

    implementation LibraryDependencies.ANDROIDX_CORE_KTX
    implementation LibraryDependencies.FRAGMENT_KTX
}
```

The problem is when I have a latest version of a library, I am unaware of it. If you have the libraries in dependencies, either the Android Studio showed you a warning with yellow color meaning the version needs to be updated or I could always go to `Analyze -> Run Inspection by Name -> Newer Library Versions Available` and run it.

Now both the ways don't work. Is there any way to check latest version availability of dependencies in centralised handling of dependencies?

Comment: use this plugin https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

Comment: @IR42 Thanks, this helps